# Issue setting up CMP and connecting to Azure Service Bus

Tags: content-hub

I have installed CMP into a Sitecore 9.1 instance and I have gone through the setup instructions as per the CMP 2.0 installation and configuration manual.
I'm seeing this error in sitecore logs which makes me believe topic is not properly set in connection strings. In the documentation it states that it should be added but not how. Anyone know what is the right format? Below is my connection string(formated for this post)

**Exception:**
Message: The argument  is null or white space.
Source: Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.TopicClient..ctor(ServiceBusConnection serviceBusConnection, String entityPath, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
   at Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.TopicClient..ctor(String connectionString, String entityPath, RetryPolicy retryPolicy)
   at Sitecore.Connector.CMP.Pipelines.Initialize.InitializeServiceBus.Process(PipelineArgs args)

**Connection String**

```
<add name="CMP.ContentHub" connectionString="ClientId=myid;ClientSecret=mysecret;UserName=username;Password=password;URI=https://myaddress-poc.stylelabs.io/en-us;" />  
<add name="CMP.ServiceBusEntityPathIn" connectionString="Endpoint=sb://myservicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=Mykey" /> 
<add name="CMP.ServiceBusSubscription" connectionString="sitecore" />  
<add name="CMP.ServiceBusEntityPathOut" connectionString="Endpoint=sb://myservicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=Mykey" />
```

Comment: I think your connection stings pathin and pathout are missing the topic names. Have you created those in azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the combined connection string (Endpoint and Topic) you can get that from Azure. When in the Azure Service Bus, click into the one of the topics and then click on the "Shared access policies" option within the Topic. It will be blank. You add a new one and will be able to grab the connection string with the combined values.

The connection strings should look like this:

- **Out**: Endpoint=sb://[SOME_HOST].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=**Read**;SharedAccessKey=[SOME_KEY];EntityPath=hub_**out**_somemoretext
- **In**: Endpoint=sb://[SOME_HOST].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=**Write**;SharedAccessKey=[SOME_KEY];EntityPath=hub_**in**_somemoretext

Comment: Thanks! The missing piece in the connection string was EntityPath!