# Connection string settings for CMP Connector

Tags: cmp

I'm trying to configure CMP for my Sitecore 10.2 instance.
Could you please tell me, what should be the values for `Incoming topic`, `Subscription name` & `Outgoing topic`, with an example.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For adding connection string setting for your CMP connector, please follow below link for reference. It contains all details that you needed related to what should be the values for `Incoming topic`, `Subscription name` & `Outgoing topic`

[Issue setting up CMP and connecting to Azure Service Bus](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/issue-setting-up-cmp-and-connecting-to-azure-service-bus)

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/connect-for-ch/50/connect-for-content-hub/add-connection-strings-for-cmp-to-your-sitecore-instance.html?utm_medium=rss&utm_source=rss_reader

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The values you are looking for should be set like this.

- Incoming topic name – m_in (The topic of the messages posted by the Sitecore Content Hub, posted after the trigger is fired)
- Incoming subscription name – sitecore
- Outgoing topic name – m_out (The topic of the messages posted to the Azure Service Bus after content is imported to Sitecore)

Refer to this article for more details.

https://visionsincode.com/2019/12/05/my-sitecore-content-hub-adventures-setting-up-sitecore-connect-for-sitecore-cmp/

Comment: For Incoming is it `m_out` & for Outgoing is it `m_in`. Shouldn't it be the other way?

Comment: Yes you are correct it should be vice versa.